# Keras: result of model.evaluate() stays high with all the weights and biases being 0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, evaluate

I created a VGG16 model using Keras application (TensorFlow backend). Then I wanted to change part of those weights and then test the accuracy of this modified model. To be direct and intuitive, I changed ALL the weights and biases in ALL layers to 0 like this:

```
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

# here is the test data and label containing 10 pictures I created.
data = np.load('./10_random_samples_array.npz')
data, label = data["X"], data["Y"]

# Modify the weights to zero
for z in [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17]:     # Conv layers
    weight_bias = model.layers[z].get_weights()
    shape_weight = np.shape(weight_bias[0])
    shape_bias = np.shape(weight_bias[1])
    weight_bias[0] = np.zeros(shape=(shape_weight[0],shape_weight[1],shape_weight[2],shape_weight[3]))
    weight_bias[1] = np.zeros(shape=(shape_bias[0],))
    model.layers[z].set_weights(weight_bias)

for z in [20,21,22]:    # FC layers
    weight_bias = model.layers[z].get_weights()
    shape_weight = np.shape(weight_bias[0])
    print(z, shape_weight)
    shape_bias = np.shape(weight_bias[1])
    weight_bias[0] = np.zeros(shape=(shape_weight[0],shape_weight[1],))
    weight_bias[1] = np.zeros(shape=(shape_bias[0],))
    model.layers[z].set_weights(weight_bias)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# To check if the weights have been modified.
print(model.layers[1].get_weights())

loss, acc = model.evaluate(data, label, verbose=1)
print(acc)
```

Then I got result like this:

```
[array([[[[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

        ...(All zero, I omit them)

        [[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]]], dtype=float32), 
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]

10/10 [==============================] - 2s 196ms/step
0.9989999532699585
```

Firstly, You can tell that all the weights and biases have already been changed to 0 but the accuracy still stays very high. That is unreasonable.(The original result returned by `model.evaluate()` is 0.9993000030517578)

Secondly, I used only 10 pictures as my test dataset. The result must be a decimal with only one digit after the point. But I got 0.9989999532699585.

I also tried to modify all weights only in Conv1-1 to zero and the result is also 0.9989999532699585. It seems that it is the minimum result. Is there something wrong with my model? Or the weights cannot be modified in this way? Or `model.evaluate()` doesn't work as I suppose?

Comment: have you trained the model.?

Comment: It's a model that Keras downloaded automatically when I create this model using 'model = VGG()' (553.5MB). So I believe it is a trained model. @Sreeram TP

Comment: What is the accuracy before you changed the weights?

Comment: It is 0.9993000030517578. By the way, I've edited my question to be clearer. Thank you very much.@Matias Valdenegro